# Get IP address of the Network Adapter of a computer having No gateway

Tags: powershell, ip-address, gateway

I've a project to add persistent routes on a list of servers which I need to do through Powershell. Our environment has 2 NIC's for every server , one production one backup. For this I need to fetch the Backup IP address of the computer , replace the last octet by 1 and use it in the 'route add' command.
The only way I can think to identify the Backup NIC is to identify the NIC which has No Gateway (Prod NIC has a Default Gateway while Backup NIC doesn't has any).
Hence my first step is to identify the Static IPAddress of that NIC which has NO Gateway i.e Default Gateway part is empty however Static IP and Subnet Mask is there.
I've tried the following till now with no luck:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter DefaultIPGateway=NULL | Select IPAddress
```

**ERROR - Get-WmiObject : Invalid Query**

```
Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter DefaultIPGateway="" | Select IPAddress
```

**ERROR - Get-WmiObject : Invalid Query**

Also I tried the following code which logically came to my mind:

```
$ntwk=Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Select IPAddress,DefaultIPGateway
forearch($net in $ntwk) 
{
 if($net.DefaultIPGateway -eq "")
 {
  Write-Output "IP of NIC with NO gateway is: "$net.IPAddress
 }
}
```

**ERROR - Get-WmiObject : Invalid Query**

Can Someone please help me out as how can I achieve this? Hope I'm clear with my query.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your OS? IIRC `win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` does not exist on WinXP.

Comment: We are using Windows 7 as desktop and the servers on which we need to remotely run the command are Windows servers 2008.

Comment: If so, check spelling of `win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` in your script. WMI objects' availability is not dependent on Powershell version. If it's correct, re-register network adapter WMI interfaces, [this link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2014/08/11/wmi-missing-or-failing-wmi-providers-or-invalid-wmi-class.aspx) has data on how to identify WMI configuration errors.

Comment: [The class description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says you need `CIMWin32.mof` to be present and valid on your servers.

Comment: Hi all,
Problem is not win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration. I'm very well able to run other queries using this wmi object. For eg. the below query runs fine on the server.
Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter DHCPEnabled=False | Select IPAdress
This query lists the all the IP address of various  NIC's which has Static IP over them.
My problem is just to find that IP address of the NIC for which there is NO Gateway. 
Any IDEAS?

Comment: Check if you can run `gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration | where {$_.ipaddress -ne $null -and $_.defaultipgateway -eq $null}`.

Comment: HI Vesper, Thanks for that idea. I'm on way to office, will check this command after reaching there in few mins and will let you know if its working or not. But I guess this is the same thing which I was doing in multiple lines which you did in single query.

Comment: Hi Vesper, your command is running fine.
I saved your query in $n and fetched the IP Address in $n. Then printed the result using Write-output "Static IP: " $n.ipaddress
And the result is:
Static IP:
10.57.121.207
fe80::303f:3bcc:87cd:84e1

Comment: And this result shows both IP as well as MAC ID.

Can we truncate this MAC ID and get only the IP Address part? 
Reason is , I need to convert this IP to gateway by replacing the last octet with 1 i.e 10.57.121.1 and then use this value to add persistent routes. Huh journey I know :)

Comment: Got the solution. We need to select the 0th record of the array like
$n.ipaddress[0] and this shows only the IP Address.
So finally the solution of this thread has been figured out and can be closed. All thanks to Vesper :)
@Vesper - Can you please post this solution as an answer so that I can mark it as best? 
Currently, since this is a comment hence I'm not able mark your answer as best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$configs=gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration | where {$_.ipaddress -ne $null -and $_.defaultipgateway -eq $null}
if ($configs -ne $null) { $yourtargetIP= $configs[0].IPAddress[0] }
# $yourtargetIP will have the IP address to make the gateway from
```

In fact, should you have more than one IPv4 address on your network card, `$configs[0].IPAddress` will have them all, one by one. More, you can assign two different IP addresses on a single network adapter. So, this will need to be tailored should you find such a server in your organization, but will work correctly if all your network adapters have a single IPv4 address.

Comment: Thanks Vesper. This is the correct solution , exactly what I was looking for :)
I think due to lack of reputation I'm not getting option to close the thread and to mark your answer as best, although I've voted it. If you can then kindly close this thread as best.

Comment: There is no "close the thread", there is "accept an answer" which essentially says "the question has been answered and that satisfied the asker", this in turn usually ends the thread as there's nothing left to catch.

Comment: Done. :)
I guess its showing from your end as well.

Answer (score 3):

Get-NetIPConfiguration |select IPv4Address, InterfaceAlias

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified which PowerShell version you are using. If you are lucky enough to have PowerShell 4.0, you may also use `Get-NetIPConfiguration`:

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration | where {$_.IPv4DefaultGateway -eq $null }
```

Comment: Really sorry to forget to mention the version. Our environment has Powershell 2.0 , not even 3.0 :( 
But I'm sure there should be an alternative in 2.0 as well which unfortunately I'm not able to figure out.
Any ideas ?